# After a mutation, how do I update the affected data across views?

Tags: graphql, apollostack, react-apollo

[image]

I have both the `getMovies` query and `addMovie` mutation working. When `addMovie` happens though, I'm wondering how to best update the list of movies in "Edit Movies" and "My Profile" to reflect the changes. I just need a general/high-level overview, or even just the name of a concept if it's simple, on how to make this happen.

My initial thought was just to hold all of the movies in my Redux store. When the mutation finishes, it should return the newly added movie, which I can concatenate to the movies of my store.

After "Add Movie", it would pop back to the "Edit Movies" screen where you should be able to see the newly added movie, then if you go back to "My Profile", it'd be there too.

Is there a better way to do this than holding it all in my own Redux store? Is there any Apollo magic I don't know about that could possibly handle this update for me?

---

**EDIT**: I discovered the idea of `updateQueries`: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries I think this is what I want (please let me know if this is not the right approach). This seems better than the traditional way of using my own Redux store.

```
// this represents the 3rd screen in my picture
const AddMovieWithData = compose(
  graphql(searchMovies, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      search: (query) => mutate({ variables: { query } }),
    }),
  }),
  graphql(addMovie, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      addMovie: (user_id, movieId) => mutate({
        variables: { user_id, movieId },
        updateQueries: {
          getMovies: (prev, { mutationResult }) => {
            // my mutation returns just the newly added movie
            const newMovie = mutationResult.data.addMovie;

            return update(prev, {
              getMovies: {
                $unshift: [newMovie],
              },
            });
          },
        },
      }),
    }),
  })
)(AddMovie);
```

After `addMovie` mutation, this properly updates the view in "My Profile" because it uses the `getMovies` query (woah)! I'm then passing these movies as props into "Edit Movies", so how do I update it there as well? Should I just have them both use the `getMovies` query? Is there a way to pull the new result of `getMovies` out of the store, so I can reuse it on "Edit Movies" without doing the query again?

---

**EDIT2:** Wrapping `MyProfile` and `EditMovies` both with `getMovies` query container seems to work fine. After `addMovie`, it's updated in both places due to `updateQueries` on `getMovies`. It's fast too. I think it's being cached?

**It all works, so I guess this just becomes a question of: Was this the best approach?**

Comment: for Apollo magic, show some code..

Comment: When you say "Was this the best approach?" you risk getting your question closed due to it being opinion based. However, I came here to write the answer that you came up with based on the question in the title (a well written title BTW!) so I'll do that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is

Use `updateQueries` to "inform` the queries that drive the other views that the data has changed (as you discovered).

This topic gets ongoing discussion in the react-apollo slack channel, and this answer is the consensus that I'm aware of: there's no obvious alternative.

Note that you can update more than one query (that's why the name is plural, and the argument is an object containing keys that match the name of all the queries that need updating).

As you may guess, this "pattern" does mean that you need to be careful in designing and using queries to make life easy and maintainable in designing mutations.    More common queires means less chance that you miss one in a mutation `updateQueries` action.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, when I discovered `updateQueries`, I was pretty amazed at how well it just worked, but being a newbie, I can't help but feel a little uncomfortable when things actually work, especially with bleeding edge tech!

Do you have any thoughts for my side-question? Originally, only "My Profile" had the `getMovies` query, and I was just passing movies as props into "Edit Movies". Of course, this means that after the mutation, it only updates where `getMovies` is... so only on "My Profile". Was adding `getMovies` to "Edit Movies", so it updates there too, the right thing to do here?

Comment: This is what I allude to in the "careful design and use of queries" :)   I think the answer is "yes".    Note that other options include having both those components inside another one that is the container, and does the query, and passes the move list as props.   This is only an option if it makes sense in the UI design though (in my app that looks just like yours, "edit movies" is a modal and so can take props from "my profile" and gets updated when "my profile" container does... but modals are often not a great idea :O ).  Maybe see you in https://apollostack.slack.com/archives/react-apollo

Comment: From the official docs:

"We recommend using `update` instead of `updateQueries`. updateQueries will be removed in the next version of Apollo Client."

[src](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#graphql-mutation-options-updateQueries)

Answer (score 1):

The Apollo Client only updates the store on update mutations. So when you use create or delete mutations you need to tell Apollo Client how to update. I had expected the store to update automatically but it doesn’t…

I have founded a workaround with `resetStore` just after doing your mutation.
You reset the store just after doing the mutation. Then when you will need to query, the store is empty, so apollo refetch fresh data.

here is the code:

```
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo'

...

  deleteCar = async id => {
    await this.props.deleteCar({
      variables: { where: {
        id: id
      } },
    })
    this.props.client.resetStore().then(data=> {
      this.props.history.push('/cars')
    })
  }


...


export default compose(
  graphql(POST_QUERY, {
    name: 'carQuery',
    options: props => ({
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      variables: {
        where: {
          id: props.match.params.id,
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
  graphql(DELETE_MUTATION, {
    name: 'deleteCar',
  }),
  withRouter,
  withApollo
)(DetailPage)
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/alan345/naperg
Ther error before the hack `resetStore`
[image]